# How to use jQuery.validation on Checkboxes generated by jQuery.repeater?

Tags: jquery, laravel, jquery.repeater

I'm using DubFriend/jquery.repeater to repeat a few fields, proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation to export Laravel validation rules, and jQuery.validation to validate them.

**Checkboxes** processed by jquery.repeater, always get an extra [] after the name.

The example in question is the following:

```
<div data-repeater-list="group-prof_entities">
    <div data-repeater-item>
       <input name="ep_is_default" type="checkbox">
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery.Repeater initializes it, and now looks like this (First one):

```
<input name="group-prof_entities[0][ep_is_default][]" type="checkbox">
```

Bellow the Laravel rule and the JsValidation expected field name:

```
'group-prof_entities.*.ep_is_default' => 'required',
```

```
group-prof_entities[*][ep_is_default]
```

If I add the brackets to the Laravel rule it then expects this:

```
group-prof_entities[*][ep_is_default[]]
```

That's no good.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

I've tried to manually delete the "[]" in the generated name, and the rule apparently worked fine.

I even tried to remove that "[]" and built a function that runs on the booting of the jquery.repeater, on a new copy of elements, but it fails on deleting an element, because indexes are recalculated and the "[]" is re-inserted.

Thanks.

Comment: dont use `jquery.repeater` or change the validation rules. BTW `'group-prof_entities.*.ep_is_default' => 'required',` still works and prevents the input array to be empty

Comment: @N69S Changing the rule seems to be a problem, since it will be processed by JsValidation and will point to a non existing field. Can you recommend any decent replacement for jquery.repeater?

Comment: If you want to have multiple fields in the same input name, you have to use an array (`{inputName}[]`) using `jquery.repeater` or any other solution. you're better off changing the validation rules.

Comment: @N69S Can you suggest a validation rule it would make sense?
I've tried a few and none is attached by JsValidation to the correct field name.

Comment: what is the rule you're trying to implement ? cause just `required` ensures that the input array is not empty if sent. it will not enforce its presence

Comment: @N69S The rule is: 
There must be at least one checkbox of "prof_entities.*.ep_is_default" selected.

Comment: check this https://ericlbarnes.com/2015/04/04/laravel-array-validation/

Comment: @N69S Thank you for your time and the reference, but that example is outdated and doesn't address the issue.